# Post Different data inside single form using <a href>

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

I have a two `ActionMethods` for **Get and Post** . and in Post I am getting the ID and returning the result to another `view`. 
Here it is my Action Methods

```
 public ActionResult Select()
    {
        if (!General.ValidateSession())
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
        }
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Select(int id)
    {
        if ((int)Session["DepartmentID"] != id && Session["Role"].ToString() != "ADMIN" && Session["Role"].ToString() != "FUNCTIONAL HEAD" )
        {
            ViewData["norights"] = "toAccess";
            return View("NoAccess");
        }
        var Result = safetyFile.getSelectedDepartmentFiles(id).Select(x => new ViewModel.SafetyFileViewModel   //Notification 
        {
            ID = x.ID,
            UploadedBy = x.UploadBy,
            FileDescription = x.FileDesscription,
            UploadedDate = x.UploadedDate,
            DepartmentFor = depRep.SelectByID(x.DepartmentID).Department,
            FileCategory = category.SelectByID(x.FileCategoryID).CategoryName,
            SafetyFileName = x.MultipleFile

        });
        return View("ListDocuments", Result);
    }
```

Here It is my View for this method.

```
<form id="search" method="post">
<a href="/file/select/1" onclick="this.form.submit()">HSEQ Document</a>
<a href="/file/select/2" onclick="this.form.submit()">HSEQ Document</a>
<a href="/file/select/3" onclick="this.form.submit()">HSEQ Document</a>
</form>
```

I want to post from `href` link , Like I am having different ID in each `href`.

Whenever I clicked anchor tag it call get method.

I tried `@Ajax.ActionLink` and was working fine but that approach didn't return another view from post method that is `ListDocument`.

In Short: I want to call a post method every time i click Anchor tag.

Comment: That's not a proper way to use `onclick` triggering form submit (anchor links will automatically redirects to URL referenced in `href` attribute by GET method). You must use `preventDefault()` before calling form submit.

Comment: And what is your `<form>`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke All i want is to call a post method , I tried ajax.actionlink and that was working fine , but did not return another view inside post methd

Comment: `POST` methods are usually used to **send** datas to the server. `GET` are used to **fetch** datas. Maybe the logic you want to use is a misinterpretation

Comment: I searched that and i found redirects don't work with an AJAX post

Comment: A link makes a GET, not a POST - you need to submit a form that makes a post to your method

Comment: `Ajax.ActionLink` doesn't immediately reload the page with another view (you need `location.href` to do so). You should use normal form submit instead.

Comment: Why are you wanting to make a POST? Your POST method is not changing/saving data, so it should be just a GET. But if you do want a post, then you need 3 separate `<form>` elements (with `action="/file/select/1"` etc) and submit buttons (styled to look like a link if that what you want)

Comment: @StephenMuecke that makes sense to me .. Thanks !

Comment: And why are you calling a method named `Select` when you want to return a view named `ListDocuments`?

Comment: So I should remove select method for post , and should call ListDoument from href element directly and get ID in ListDocument.

Comment: Changing the method to `public ActionResult ListDocuments(int id)` (a GET, not a POST) with `return View(Result);`, and using `@Html.ActionLink("HSEQ Document", "ListDocuments", "file", new { id = 1 }, null })` makes more sense

Comment: Got it .. yep I was using more code by using extra post method .. Thanks !